# difficulties on making panel scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this

[image: layout]

a simple panel using bootstrap which displays a list of departments in the table and with an input field in the bottom with a button to add. This panel is fixed in height, and as you can see, the content is overflowing the panel. I tried to make it scrollable but I still get the same end result.

What I want is for the the content in the table to be inside the panel and scrollable.

```css
.panel-primary {
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.panel__add-pos {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-heading {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel-body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.department-actions {
  width: 70px;
  height: 14px;
}
.department-actions a {
  color: #d2d2d2;
}
.department-actions a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
.panel__add-dept form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 97%;
}
.panel__input-container {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.panel__input-container:focus {
  border-color: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none);
}
[class*="btn"] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary panel__add-dept">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="panel-title">LIST OF DEPARTMENT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Department Name</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Accounting Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="1" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="1">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="http://localhost/" id="list-dept-form" data-panel_name="Department" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div class="form-group add-department">
        <input class="form-control panel__input-container" id="new_department" type="text" name="new_department" placeholder="Add new department" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button--dark pull-right" id="add-department" name="submit_dept">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scroll bar will not be added unless the content is taller than the parent. However, the parent must also have a limited height.

```css
.panel-primary {
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.panel__add-pos {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-heading {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel-body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px; /* --- like this --- */
}
.panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.department-actions {
  width: 70px;
  height: 14px;
}
.department-actions a {
  color: #d2d2d2;
}
.department-actions a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
.panel__add-dept form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 97%;
}
.panel__input-container {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.panel__input-container:focus {
  border-color: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none);
}
[class*="btn"] {
  border-radius: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary panel__add-dept">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="panel-title">LIST OF DEPARTMENT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Department Name</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Accounting Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="1" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="1">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Department</td>
          <td>
            <div class="department-actions pull-right">
              <a href="http://localhost/" data-id="2" class="click-open">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" data-id="2">
                <i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="click-edit" data-name="Department" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="http://localhost/" id="list-dept-form" data-panel_name="Department" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div class="form-group add-department">
        <input class="form-control panel__input-container" id="new_department" type="text" name="new_department" placeholder="Add new department" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button--dark pull-right" id="add-department" name="submit_dept">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.panel__add-pos {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: none;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Try that css for your code

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.panel {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and remove the styles you have on `.panel-body`